# Can't find a mistake. C++, strings

Tags: c++, string, uppercase

I should write a programm, that will show only the words, that have an uppercase letter in the end.

For example: 
"somE wordS just RighT there" -> "somE wordS RighT"

But there is something wrong with my code and I can't find a mistake.
(Sorry for this code, it might be really messed up)

```
string LastUpperSymbol(string text) {

    int i = 0, space, next, sortEl = 0;
    string textcopy = text;
    int size = textcopy.size();
    string sorted;
    string alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
    if (textcopy[0] != alph[26]) {
        space = text.find(" ");
        if(isupper(textcopy[space-1])) {
            sorted.append(textcopy, 0, space+1);
        }
        while(space < textcopy.size()) {
            next = space+1;
            space = text.find(" ", next);
            if(space == -1) {
                if(isupper(textcopy[size])) {
                    sorted.append(textcopy, next, textcopy[size]);
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(isupper(textcopy[space-1])) {
                sorted.append(textcopy, next, space+1);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //something
    }
    cout << sorted << endl;
    return text;
}
int main() {

    string text = "somE wordS just RighT there";
    cout << LastUpperSymbol(text);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: It's likely that your string implementation has a debug flag that you can use to enable things like out-of-bounds checks, though I could be thinking of other library parts rather than `string` specifically. If nothing else, out-of-bounds can be made loud by using `at` instead of `[]`. You can also try a sanitizer tool.

Comment: My advice is to learn how to use your debugger to single step through the code looking at variables at each step.

Comment: Always check the result of `find` to make sure it is not `std::string::npos`.

Comment: @WhozCraig In C++11 and above `textcopy[textcopy.size()]` is perfectly legal and gives you the null terminator(`charT{}`).  You cannot modify it but looking at it is fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver Tis true. Six years and I'm still getting used to that. Thanks for keeping me honest. Still, `textcopy[size]` makes for an odd *count* for that [`append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), don't you think?

Comment: @WhozCraig No problem.  It's probably not want they want though.  As far as I can tell that if will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library already provides code for the vast majority of what you need to do here, so it's probably easier to just use what's there instead of trying to figure out the problems in your existing code.

I'd probably do the job something like this:

```
std::string silly_filter(std::string const &in) {

    std::istringstream buff(in);
    std::ostringstream out;

    std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buff),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, " "),
        [](std::string const &s) {
            return ::isupper((unsigned char)*s.crbegin());
        });
    return out.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the

`else if(isupper(textcopy[space-1])) {
            sorted.append(textcopy, next, **space+1**);
 }`

the space + 1 is the number of string to append. So if next=5 the string would be w so the second parameter should be length of 'wordS' i.e 5 in this case the second parameter keeps on growing.